# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (14,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a classification model in a distributed way. I am using TensorflowOnSpark library developed by Yahoo. The example I am using [github link](https://github.com/yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark/blob/master/examples/mnist/keras/mnist_mlp.py#L68)

I am using dataset other than mnist which is used in example mentioned in the github link. This dataset I am using is of dimensions as follows after preprocessing (260000,28047)  and also the classes(labels) range from 0:13.

> ```
> >>> import os
> >>> import tensorflow as tf
> >>> from tensorflow.python import keras
> >>> from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
> >>> from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential, load_model, save_model
> >>> from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
> >>> from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback, TensorBoard
> >>> from tensorflow.python.saved_model import builder as saved_model_builder
> >>> from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
> >>> from tensorflow.python.saved_model.signature_def_utils_impl import predict_signature_def
> >>> from tensorflowonspark import TFNode
> >>> from pyspark.context import SparkContext
> >>> from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
> >>> from tensorflowonspark import TFCluster
> >>> import numpy
> >>>
> >>> 
> ...
> >>>
> >>> data = sc.textFile('ReducedFeatures.tsv')
> >>>
> >>> data = data.map(lambda l: l.encode("UTF8", "ignore").split('\t'))
> >>>
> >>> labels = data.map(lambda x: x[1])
> >>> data = data.map(lambda x: x[19:28066])
> >>>
> >>> header = data.first()
> >>> data = data.filter(lambda line: line != header)
> >>> label_header = labels.first()
> >>> labels = labels.filter(lambda line: line != label_header)
> >>>
> >>> #convert values to float
> ... convertToFloat = lambda data: [float(str(x)) for x in data]
> >>> dataset = data.map(convertToFloat)
> >>> labels = labels.map(lambda x:float(x))
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> labels = labels.map(lambda x: keras.utils.to_categorical(x, num_classes=14))
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> # zip the data as tuple
> ... dataRDD = dataset.zip(labels)
> >>>
> >>> sampledata = dataRDD.take(20)
> >>>
> >>> model = Sequential()
> >>> model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28047,)))
> >>> model.add(Dropout(0.2))
> >>> model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
> >>> model.add(Dropout(0.2))
> >>> model.add(Dense(14, activation='softmax'))
> >>>
> >>> model.summary()
> _________________________________________________________________
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
> =================================================================
> dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               14360576
> _________________________________________________________________
> dropout (Dropout)            (None, 512)               0
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               262656
> _________________________________________________________________
> dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 14)                7182
> =================================================================
> Total params: 14,630,414
> Trainable params: 14,630,414
> Non-trainable params: 0
> _________________________________________________________________
> >>>
> >>> model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
> ...                       optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001),
> ...                       metrics=['accuracy'])
> >>>
> >>> print("model.inputs: {}".format(model.inputs))
> model.inputs: [<tf.Tensor 'dense_input:0' shape=(?, 28047) dtype=float32>]
> >>> print("model.outputs: {}".format(model.outputs))
> model.outputs: [<tf.Tensor 'dense_2/Softmax:0' shape=(?, 14) dtype=float32>]
> >>>
> >>> def generate_rdd_data(dataRDD):
> ...     while True:
> ...             feature_vector = []
> ...             lbls = []
> ...             for item in dataRDD:
> ...                     #record = item[0]
> ...                     feature_vector.append(item[0])
> ...                     lbls.append(item[1])
> ...             features = numpy.array(feature_vector).astype('float32')
> ...             labels = numpy.stack(lbls).astype('float32')
> ...             return (features, labels)
> ...
> >>>
> >>> feat, lbls = generate_rdd_data(sampledata)
> >>> lbls
> array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
>        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
>        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
>        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
>        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
>        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
>        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],
>       dtype=float32)
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> x_train = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28047], name="x_train")
> >>> y_train = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 14], name="y_train")
> >>>
> ...
> >>> model.fit_generator(generator=generate_rdd_data(sampledata),steps_per_epoch=200,epochs=5,verbose=1,validation_data=(x_train, y_train))
> ```

Also Please take a look at the traceback below, I did OneHotEncoding for the labels and also while adding the outuput layers it is 14 as you can see it in the code and model summary.

```
   >     Traceback (most recent call last):
    >       File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    >       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py",
    > line 2177, in fit_generator
    >         initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
    >       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py",
    > line 104, in fit_generator
    >         val_x, val_y, val_sample_weights)
    >       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py",
    > line 992, in _standardize_user_data
    >         class_weight, batch_size)
    >       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py",
    > line 1154, in _standardize_weights
    >         exception_prefix='target')
    >       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py",
    > line 332, in standardize_input_data
    >         ' but got array with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    >     ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (14,)
```

But when I start training using the output from generator method. I get the following dimension errors for the classes. Please help

Comment: You are using the wrong loss (sparse cross-entropy), you should be using categorical cross-entropy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using wrong loss function.

`"sparse_categorical_crossentropy"` is used when your input labels are integers like `[0, 1, 2, 3, ...13`]. But your output is onehot encoded [0,0,...1,0].

So use loss function `"categorical_crossentropy"`.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```